# Unable to send a jpeg attachment to mail with C#

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am trying to send a jpeg attachment to some email templates through a MailSenderService I have connected to my C# web application. I am using a .NET 6.0 version for my application.

The weird and bizarre thing is that I can send all types of documents and files such as `.docx`,`.doc`, `.png`, `.pdf` as attachments through my emails but whenever I am loading `jpeg` files they are not attached to the email.

My C# code for converting the full path of my files to a `base64` string which is saved in my database is this:

```
 string base64DNI = String.Empty;

 if (newEsp.rutadni != null && newEsp.rutadni != old.rutadni){
   // Lst is the text that goes together with the attachment in the email if the condition above is true
   Lst += $"<p style='font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Montserrat','Arial',sans-serif; color: #6668ae;'>" + "Se ha subido un nuevo documento de DNI." + "</p>";
   using (StreamReader strm = new StreamReader(newEsp.rutadni, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
   {         
          Stream s = strm.BaseStream;
          BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(s);
          docBytes = r.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(r.BaseStream.Length));
          base64DNI = Convert.ToBase64String(docBytes);
          r.Close();
          s.Close();
         strm.Close();
    }
  }
```

After converting my file to a `base64` string, I am using a `try catch` block to send all my attachments through the email:

```
  try {
      base64DNI = base64DNI.Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
      await mailSenderService.EmailEditUser(Lst, base64DNI);
      response.status = "OK";
      response.message = "Su solicitud se ha enviado con éxito.";
  }catch (Exception ex){
       response.status = "KO";
       response.message = "Se ha producido un error. Por favor, intentelo de nuevo.";
    }
```

Furthemore, I am calling an asynchronous function from my mailSenderService which is this one, it takes the `Lst` string which is the text of the email plus the generated `base64` string from the conversion in the `try catch` block in the above explanation.

Finally, I am putting everything together in another `try catch` block which receives various properties for the request such as the sender, password, receiver, a mail template id and an email data model.

```
public async Task EmailEditUser(string old, string base64DNI){
        var Attachmentsls = new List<AttachmentData>();
        string ext;
        string nameDoc;

        if (base64DNI != "")
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetFileExtension(base64DNI)))
            {
                ext = GetFileExtension(base64DNI);
                nameDoc = "DNI." + ext;
                Attachmentsls.Add(new AttachmentData { Id = 1067, MailDataId = 1008, FileName = nameDoc, Data = base64DNI });
            }
        }
      
        try
        {
            var reqForMail = new MailSenderRequest()
            {
                From = null,
                Pass = null,
                To = mailSenderConfiguration.GetDepartmentEmails(),
                MailTemplateId = 1008,
                EmailDataModel = new MailData()
                {
                    Id = 1038,
                    MailTemplateId = 1008,
                    Properties = new List<PropertyData>
                    {
                        new PropertyData{ Id = 1067, MailDataId= 1008, ReplaceId = "Lst", Value = old},
                    },
                    Attachments = Attachmentsls
                }
            };
            ExecuteUsingMSS(mailSenderConfiguration.MSS_endpoint, reqForMail);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"Error al intentar enviar Email emailregisteredeventReports: {e.Message}");
        }
 }
```

Any help or guidance would be kindly appreciated.

Thanks you

Comment: The question doesn't contain the code that sends emails but it *does* contains several problems, which makes it surprising anything is sent. `BinaryReader` is *not* used to read binary files. The `StreamReader` isn't used at all. All that code is essentially a buggy way of writing `Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(somePath))`. Then `base64DNI.Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');` mangles the valid BASE64 string in something that's *not* valid.

Comment: Sending an attachment is easy [even with the obsolete SmptClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments?view=net-7.0). You only need to pass the path to the file you want to the `Attachment` class constructor. [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-7.0#remarks) warn against using it though, suggesting using the open source MailKit instead. [The code is similar](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Creating-Messages.htm) but can be customized a lot more

Comment: `base64DNI.Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');` is finally the problem. Removing the `.Replace('/', '_')` actually solved it. Possibly the                                               
`.Replace('+', '-')` is unnecessary also.

Comment: The explicit conversion is also unnecessary because any SMTP client you use will take care of encoding attachments

Comment: You were definitely right. The `BinaryReader` and `StreamReader` were unnecessary and totally buggy.  I only had to do this: `base64DNI = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(newEsp.rutadni));` and it worked like a charm. Thanks you for the guidance :)